# Powershell replace string from array inside foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, replace, foreach

I have a CSV file containing products, this CSV file has a column for brands and a column for categories.  I'm trying to run a foreach loop to remove the brand names from the categories column.

```
$products = import-csv X:\products.csv
$brands = $products.Brand | sort | select -unique

foreach ($item in $products) {
  $item.categories = $item.categories.Replace("Coming Soon","")
  $item.categories = $item.categories.Replace($brands,"")
}
```

The "Coming Soon" gets removed, but all the brand names that are containd in $brands still remain.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're attempting to remove *all the brand names* from each `categories` property.

Reference `$item.Brand` inside the `foreach` loop to get the corresponding one:

```bsh
foreach($item in $products){
  $item.categories = $item.categories.Replace("Coming Soon","")
  $item.categories = $item.categories.Replace($item.Brand,"")
}
```

Comment: Awesome, such a simple thing that I've overcomplicated!  Just so I'm clear on what I was doing wrong - it wasn't working because it was looking for 200+ brand names in a single property?